# Пунктуaция

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "словно" : "Моя комната, словно старый деревянный ящик, наполненный всяким хламом".

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае конструкция "словно старый деревянный ящик" является составным именным сказуемым с нулевой глагольной связкой. *Словно* здесь - частица, выражающая сравнение (предположение). Запятая НЕ нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Но вторая запятая нужна, верно? "Моя комната словно старый деревянный ящик, наполненный всяким хламом".

Comment: Причастный оборот после определяемого слова выделяется запятой, да.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1) Исходное предложение
2) Моя комната, словно старый деревянный ящик, наполнена всяким хламом.
Суть обоих предложений одна и та же, значит, и пунктуация должна быть одинаковой!

Comment: Содержание сходное, но его подача разная. В первом случае вы сравниваете комнату с деревянным ящиком, а затем даете его определение. Во втором случае вы сообщаете, что комната наполнена хламом, сравнение с деревянным ящиком является попутным.

Comment: Извините, я что-то упустила в комментариях? Вы пишите о двух случаях, двух предложениях, поясните, пожалуйста, о каких?

Comment: Первое предложение Ваше("Моя комната, словно старый деревянный ящик, наполненный всяким хламом"), основа "комната словно ящик", запятая перед союзом не нужна. Второе предложение очень похоже на ваше ("Моя комната, словно старый деревянный ящик, наполнена всяким хламом"), основа в нем - "комната наполнена", "словно ящик" - сравнительный оборот, запятые нужны.

Comment: Все, поняла. В первом предложении "наполненнЫЙ", а во втором - "наполненА". Простите, невнимательно прочла, не сразу поняла о каких двух вариантах идет речь. Спасибо, что пояснили.